# OpenCV: read matrix value

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, background-image, pixel

I want to count the number of white points in a background image which is only black and white. I have a code like this:

```
int count = 0; 
for ( int j = 0; j < Image.rows; j ++ )
    {
    for ( int i = 0; i < Image.cols; i ++ )
        {
            if ( Image.at<int>(i,j) >= 150 )
            {
                count ++ ;
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason, the above code doesn't work, it just stops reacting. I checked, and the line" if ( Image.at(i,j) >= 150 ) " causes the problem. My "Image" is a "cv::Mat", with "CV_8UC3" type. Is there someone can help me? Thank you.

Comment: Do a cout of `Image.at<int>(i,j)`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Image.at<int>(j,i)`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. The cout partial result is something like this: 
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1109311264,11117845974,9668574984,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2514654812,1101231542,121415421,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...

I changed it into "Image.at<int>(j,i)", and the output of cout is like this:7745580006,-1869970562,1835821674,-1987475062,...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to my comment to Robin's answer, your error is that you try to access an image of CV_8UC3 type as ints. If you want to check grey levels, do something like this (note the "unsigned char" instead of "int", as in Robin's answer).

```
cv::Mat greyscale;
cv::cvtColor(image,grayscale,CV_RGB2GRAY);
// either, most elegant:
int count = cv::countNonZero(greyscale >= 150);
// or, copied from Robin's answer:
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < greyscale.rows; ++i) {
    const unsigned char* row = greyscale.ptr<unsigned char>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < greyscale.cols; j++) {
        if (row[j] >= 150)
            ++count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Etarion, Robin, and all others who answered my question, thank you so much for your help. Now it works fine. I used the code Etarion provided lastly. Best regards.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is much neater:

```
Mat result;
threshold(Image,result,150,255,THRESH_BINARY);
int white_count = countNonZero(result);
```

Comment: Yes, this is indeed much efficient. Thank you :)

Comment: This is most probably the fastest way to do it - threshold and countNonZero are optimized better then the for-loop approach

Comment: @ederman You're welcome.
I don't get it, if it helped, why down vote? (to whom it concerns!)

Comment: @Kamyar, I didn't down vote it, I selected Robin's answer for reference, then also voted your answer as useful. Did I miss something here? Please don't misunderstand anything. Thank you.

Comment: @ederman, I knew! :) I was talking about the one who did it. I noted: to whom it concerns. Anyway, I'm glad if it helped anyone...

Answer (score 3):

Write `Image.at<unsigned char>(j,i)` not `Image.at<unsigned char>(i,j)` if you are using i for cols and j for rows.

Comment: I changed it into (j,i) lastly, thank you for pointing this error out for me. Then I used "countNonZero" method that other friends provided here. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sammy, da tu nu prea ai treaba pe acolo? :) Mai bine da-mi si mie un up! :)

Comment: iti fac up, daca schimbi int cu uchar, ca asa nu merge ;) Si-apoi ma mai relaxez si eu, ca pe mine nu ma pandeste nimeni

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to access the row before the column, meaning you should swap i and j. 

Substitute `if ( Image.at<int>(i,j) >= 150 )` with `if ( Image.at<int>(j,i) >= 150 )`

There are easier ways to access a Mat though. 
OpenCV provides an STL-like iterator which is easy to use and if you want to access all the elements very easy to use. Example:

```
int count = 0;
MatConstIterator_<int> it = Image.begin<int>(), it_end = Image.end<int>();
for(; it != it_end; ++it)
    if ((*it) >= 150)
        ++count;
```

Last but not least you could also get a pointer to each row and access the data via the plain [] operator:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < Image.rows; ++i) {
    const int* Ii = Image.ptr<int>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < Image.cols; j++) {
        if (Ii[j] >= 150)
            ++count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Robin for your answer. I tried iterator, but for the "if((*it) >=15)" line, it gives an error saying " no operator >= matches these operands".

Comment: Even easier than your first way, `cv::Mat tmp; cv::threshold(image, tmp, 150, 1, cv::THRESH_BINARY); count = cv::countNonZero(tmp);`

Answer (score 1):

you could access the CV_8UC3 Pixels with opencv bytes vectors (unsigned char pixels) !
In this case you can make the following (now you could also use some special color threshold)

```
int channel = 0;
Image.at<Vec3b>( row , col )[channel]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I learned how to use color threshold :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of methods to access the cv::Mat image,
if you want to directly access the color image(**CV_8UC3**),
it could be implemented by following:

```
int count = 0;
int threshold = 150;
for(int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++) {
   for(int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++) {
      //white point which means that the point in every channel(BGR)
      //are all higher than threshold!
      if(img.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(j)[i][0] > threshold && 
         img.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(j)[i][1] > threshold 
         img.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(j)[i][2] > threshold ) {
             count++;
         }

    }
 }
```

but I recommend that if you only want to count white points, you can just convert image into grayscale
(**CV_8UC1**), and do as following:

```
cv::Mat img;
cv::cvtColor(src,img,CV_BGR2RGB);
int count = 0;
int threshold = 150;
for(int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++) {
   for(int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++) {
      if(img.ptr<uchar>(j)[i] > threshold) {
            count++;
      }
   }
}
```

Finally, note that access cv::Mat image by **img.ptr< [Imagetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569097/opencv-c-how-access-pixel-value-cv-32f-through-uchar-data-pointer)>** will not check the accessed point is correct, so if you certainly know the range of image, the access image by ptr will be fine, otherwise, you can do by **img.at< Imagetype>()**, it will check every point is correct at every call,[why access image by ptr is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277643/opencv-mat-array-access-which-way-is-the-fastest-for-and-why)
so if there are invalid accessed point, it will assert you!