# OpenCV Mat array access, which way is the fastest for and why?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencv, mat

I am wondering about the way of accessing data in Mat in OpenCV. As you know, we can access to get data in many ways. I want to store image (Width x Height x 1-depth) in Mat and looping access each pixel in the image. Using ptr<>(irow) to get row-pixel and then access each column in the row is the best way? or using at<>(irow,jcol) is the best?  or using directly calculate the index by using index = irow*Width + jrow is the best? Anyone know the reason.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can find information here in the documentation: [the basic image container](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#matthebasicimagecontainer) and [how to scan images](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html?highlight=accessing%20element).

I advice you to practice with `at` ([here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat#mat-at)) if you are not experienced with OpenCV or with C language types hell. But the fastest way is `ptr` as [Nolwenn answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14277822/433685) because you avoid the type checking.

Answer (score 3):

`at<T>` does a range check at every call, thus making it slower than `ptr<T>`, but safer.

So, if you're confident that your range calculations are correct and you want the best possible speed, use `ptr<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but I think the current answers are somehow misleading.

Calling both `at<T>(...)` and `ptr<T>(...)` will check the boundaries in the debug mode. If the `_DEBUG` macro is not defined, they will basically calculate `y * width + x` and give you either the pointer to the data or the data itself. So using `at<T>(...)` in release mode is equivalent to calculating the pointer yourself, but safer because calculating the pointer is not just `y * width + x` if the matrix is just a sub-view of another matrix. In debug mode, you get the safety checks.

I think the best way is to process the image row-by-row, getting the row pointer using `ptr<T>(y)` and then using `p[x]`. This has the benefit that you don't have to count with various data layouts and still plain pointer for the inner loop.

You can use plain pointers all the way, which would be most efficient because you avoid one the multiplication per row, but then you need to use `step1(i)` to advance the pointer. I think that using `ptr<T>(y)` is a nice trade-off.

Answer (score 3):

According to the official documentations, they suggest that the most efficient way is to get the pointer to the row first, and then just use the plain C operator []. It also saves a multiplication for each iteration.

```
// compute sum of positive matrix elements
// (assuming that M isa double-precision matrix)
double sum=0;
for(int i = 0; i < M.rows; i++)
{
    const double* Mi = M.ptr<double>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < M.cols; j++)
        sum += std::max(Mi[j], 0.);
}
```