# OpenCV C++: how access pixel value CV_32F through uchar data pointer

Tags: opencv

Briefly, I would like to know if it is possible to directly access pixel value
of a CV_32F Mat, through Mat member "uchar* data".

I can do it with no problem if Mat is CV_8U, for example:

```
// a matrix 5 columns and 6 rows, values in [0,255], all elements initialised at 12
cv:Mat A;
A.create(5,6, CV_8UC1);
A = cv::Scalar(12);

//here I successfully access to pixel [4,5]
uchar *p = A.data;
int value = (uchar) p[4*A.step + 5];
```

The problem is when I try to do the same operation with the following matrix,

```
// a matrix 5 columns, 6 rows, values in [0.0, 1.0], all elements initialised at 1.2
cv::Mat B;
B.create(5,6, CV_32FC1);
B = cv::Scalar(1.2);

//this clearly does not work, no syntax error but erroneous value reported!
uchar *p = B.data;  
float value = (float) p[4*B.step + 5];

//this works, but it is not what I want to do!
float value = B.at<float>(4,5);
```

Thanks a lot, Valerio

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `float *p = B.data`;

Comment: mmm no, you can't do this! B.data is a pointer to uchar! This is a data member in Mat!

Comment: oups. sorry. i rushed to comment. by the way. vote up the answers you liked and accept the one which works.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `ptr` method which returns pointer to matrix row:

```
for (int y = 0; y < mat.rows; ++y)
{
    float* row_ptr = mat.ptr<float>(y);
    for (int x = 0; x < mat.cols; ++x)
    {
        float val = row_ptr[x];
    }
}
```

You can also cast `data` pointer to float and use `elem_step` instead of `step` if matrix is continous:

```
float* ptr = (float*) mat.data;
size_t elem_step = mat.step / sizeof(float);
float val = ptr[i * elem_step + j];
```

Comment: how would you change this code so that it works with several channels?

Answer (score 5):

Note that CV_32F means the elements are `float` instead of `uchar`. The "F" here means "float". And the "U" in CV_8U stands for `unsigned integer`. Maybe that's why your code doesn't give the right value. By declaring p as `uchar*`, `p[4*B.step+5]` makes p move to the fifth row and advance `sizeof(uchar)*5`, which tend to be wrong. You can try

```
float value = (float) p[4*B.step + 5*B.elemSize()]
```

but I'm not sure if it will work.
Here are some ways to pass the data of [i, j] to value:

1. `value = B.at<float>(i, j)`
2. `value = B.ptr<float>(i)[j]`
3. `value = ((float*)B.data)[i*B.step+j]`

The 3rd way is not recommended though, since it's easy to overflow. Besides, a 6x5 matrix should be created by `B.create(6, 5, CV_32FC1)`, I think?

Comment: Thanks, the 3rd way was what I was looking for. Nevertheless there is something still unclear to me. I used this formula:

Comment: Ok, please clarify this point: in 3rd mode you use number 5. SHould it be B.step instead number 5? Thanks.

Comment: @valerio_sperati Yes it should. Sorry I forgot to fix that.