# Accessing 3 Channel matrix with pointer in opencv/c++

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, matrix

I have a matrix `cv::Mat xyz` of type `CV_32FC3` storing 3d coordinates of an image. I've to check every `z` coordinate according to a certain condition. I tried it with a pointer to one row and then go over the cols, but somewhere is a mistake, since I get wrong values, as soon as I want to eval the pointer. (Don't get confused the `vector<Point> pts`, I just need to store the corresponding position in a vector. Here my code:

```
const int rows = xyz.rows;
const int cols = xyz.cols;

for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {

    uchar* p_3d = _xyz.ptr(row);//Take a pointer to j-th row of the image to be drawn

    for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
        //Check z channel being valid
        if(p_3d[2] != -1) {
            pts.push_back(Point(col,row));
        }
        p_3d += 3;
    }
}
```

Does someone see my error?
How do I use pointer to rows correctly?

Comment: _xyz.ptr<Vec3b>(row); see http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html

Comment: Also take a look at here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569097/opencv-c-how-access-pixel-value-cv-32f-through-uchar-data-pointer

Comment: @AndreySmorodov has the link that actually addresses this question. It isn't really a duplicate of the one shown by Derman, because to properly use pointers to reference a multi channel Mat data, you need to understand how channels are arranged in memory, which isn't addressed by the redirect.