# matlab find function implementation in opencv?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing, mat

I have this matlab code ,where i tried to find the 'j' in matrix color.I cant find a usefull function in opencv which can do the same job like matlab find do.i have tried some iterative method with 3 for loops ,but that were too cumbersome,Can you guys help me out?

```
if (find(Colorr==j))
    tt=tt+1;
    test=[test;ColorValues(:,j,1),ColorValues(:,j,2),ColorValues(:,j,3)];
end
```

this is the code i have written to covert to opencv

```
for(j=0;j<ColorValues.cols/2;j++)
    for(i=0;i<Color.cols;i++){
        if(j=input[Color.step*i+1]){
            tt++;
            for(k=0;k<ColorValues.rows;k++){

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: this find command will be very use full,if we can implement it in opencv.

Comment: Maybe an [already implemented operation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) could fit you. Maybe, the best choice you have is the cumbersome way. An idea would be e.g. to modify minMaxIdx() and return a container with desired indexes.

Comment: i am beginner in opencv. So could not understand all function well. Can you please elaborate little

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070139/opencv-read-matrix-value).

Comment: this didnt answer my question.

Comment: Please move the code up in the question.

Comment: i hope my code will do this job..but i need simple function rather this cumbersome code, since sometimes this may cause runtime problem.

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what you want. What is the actual operation you wish to perform?

Comment: i have a matrix 'color' having 1 rows and 'n' number of columns, i want to check whether the matrix contain 'j' as its data. if so, then rest of the operation will be performed.

Comment: if you think my question is use full, do not forget to vote it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Color` is a properly initialized single-channel `cv::Mat`, you can use the combination of overloaded `operator==` and [`cv::countNonZero()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=mean#int%20countNonZero%28InputArray%20src%29) to do what you wish. `operator==` returns a mask where each element is one if the value in `Color` matches `j`, or zero otherwise.

```
if(cv::countNonZero(Color == j))
{
   // Do something...
}
```